# Invoke custom functionality on save/update/delete of a record on any database table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to invoke some functionality on save/update/delete of a record on every database table.

Don't want to use events because that will only work with eloquent and not schema builder. Whatever is the approach(eloquent and schema builder) when a record is saved/update/delete on any object, I need to invoke some business logic.

Any inputs how can I do that?

Only option that I can think of is overriding the standard methods? Is that even suggested?

Comment: Use database triggers. You also may want to read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I explored triggers on DB, but for some reason I want to take care of this in the application as I have other features built on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct in your assesment that the only way to archieve this is to overwrite the Query Builder in Laravel.

I would highly recommend that you pivot to only using Eloquent and not the Query Builder directly. Unless you do some highly advanced queries, you should be able to do the same queries with Eloquent alone.

Comment: Another problem I see is, for every model I need to implement the created event. Hence I was looking at overriding the core functionality.

Comment: I think you can listen to the creation of any Eloquent model with `eloquent.created: *`

Comment: Yeah but I need to do it for every model. What I need is something like overriding the save method so that whenever any record on any table is saved it triggers my save method.